# Как закрыть все таски если хотя бы одна закончилась

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

Есть `decimal` параметр. Предположим он равен 10. Есть `Task` которая раз в `100ms` уменьшает его на `0.1`. Как только параметр становится равен `1`, таска должна завершится и больше параметр не уменьшать. Работает без проблем если `Task` только одна. Но если их `2, 3, 100...` то параметр в итоге станет меньше `1`. Я пробую использовать `CancellationToken` что бы завершить все таски, но результат всё такой же. Мой код:

```
    class Program
    {
        static decimal param = 108;
        static CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        static CancellationToken token;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int tasksCount = 16;
            token = cancelTokenSource.Token;

            Console.WriteLine("Start Param = {0}", param);
            Console.WriteLine("Tasks Count = {0}", tasksCount);

            var tasksList = new List<Task>();
            for (var i = 0; i < tasksCount; i++)
            {
                Task task = new Task(Decrementation, token);
                tasksList.Add(task);
            }
            tasksList.ForEach(x => x.Start());
            Task.WaitAny(tasksList.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", param);
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void Decrementation()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (CanTakeMore())
                {
                    Task.Delay(100);
                    param = param - 0.1m;
                }
                else
                {
                    cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool CanTakeMore()
        {
            if (param > 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Вывод бывает разный, но он всегда меньше 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: так у вас происходит не атомарное проверка и декримент параметра, т.к. два потока могу проверить что `param > 1` и он на самом деле будет больше 1, например 1.1, и два сделают декремент.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten т.е. `CancellationToken` тут не при чем ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вывод бывает разный

Потому что этот код не является потокобезопасным, вычитания и проверки значения надо делать под локом.

- `Task.Delay` не работает без `await`
- конструктор `Task` не стоит использовать, совсем, это устаревший метод создания тасок
- `CancellationTokenSource` это `IDisposable`, надо использовать `using`
- избегайте глобальных ресурсов, полей и свойств в многопоточке, используйте аргументы методов и возвращаемые значения
- использовать синхронные комбинаторы `WaitAny` и `WaitAll` тоже не стоит, есть асинхронные

Давайте добавим немного потокобезопасности. Если все сделать правильно, даже токен отмены не нужен, незачем масло масляное устраивать, нсли все методы сами безопасно завершатся.

```
class Program
{
    static decimal param = 108;
    static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    static asynс Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int tasksCount = 16;

        Console.WriteLine($"Start Param = {param}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Tasks Count = {tasksCount}");
        
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tasksCount; i++)
        {
            Task task = Task.Run(Decrementation);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
            
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine($"Result = {param}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Decrementation()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (CanTakeMore()) 
                    param -= 0.1m;
                else
                    return;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100); // здесь бы имел смысл токен отмены и await Task.Delay, если бы ожидание было длительным
                               // напишите коммент, нсли надо показать асинхронный код с отменой
        }
    }

    private static bool CanTakeMore()
    {
        return param > 1;
    }
}
```